# How to add custom transient property in Codable struct

Tags: ios, swift4, codable

I have following Codable struct that working as expected

```
struct VideoAlbum: Codable {


 let id, image: String?
 let video, mediaType: JSONNull?
 let type, deleted, createdOn: String?
 let modifiedOn: JSONNull?

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, image, video
    case mediaType = "media_type"
    case type, deleted
    case createdOn = "created_on"
    case modifiedOn = "modified_on"
 }

}
```

// MARK: Encode/decode helpers

```
class JSONNull: Codable {
public init() {}

public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    if !container.decodeNil() {
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
    }
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    try container.encodeNil()
}
}
```

**Now I need custom property to be added that are not coming from API** to track video position so I modified it

```
struct VideoAlbum: Codable {
    
    let id, image: String?
    let video, mediaType: JSONNull?
    let type, deleted, createdOn: String?
    let modifiedOn: JSONNull?
    
    var isPlaying:Bool? // CUSOTM PROPERTY 
    var currentTime:CMTime? // CUSOTM PROPERTY 
    var timeObserver:Any? // CUSOTM PROPERTY  
    var pausedByUser:Bool? // CUSOTM PROPERTY 
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, image, video
        case mediaType = "media_type"
        case type, deleted
        case createdOn = "created_on"
        case modifiedOn = "modified_on"

        case isPlaying,pausedByUser
        case currentTime
        case timeObserver
    }
}
```

However it is showing

> error Type 'VideoAlbum' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

**Is there any way to not use some property as Codable ?**

I know issue is with **CMTime** and **Any** I don't know how to fix it

I have search many question but there is all property are from API, not found for custom property Any one suggest me any solution or alternate way ?

Comment: What do you mean by `custom` property? Are they your custom `Type` or just some properties that aren't in your JSON response?

Comment: @nayem Some property not in json response  and which type is anything like Class or Any , or Struct

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't want to decode those 4 properties, just don't include them in the `CodingKeys` (and don't forget to explicitly provide default values for them, so that the decoder can initialize the object properly):

```
struct VideoAlbum: Codable {

    let id, image: String?
    let video, mediaType: JSONNull?
    let type, deleted, createdOn: String?
    let modifiedOn: JSONNull?

    var isPlaying: Bool? = nil
    var currentTime: CMTime? = nil
    var timeObserver: Any? = nil
    var pausedByUser: Bool? = nil

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        // include only those that you want to decode/encode
        case id, image, video
        case mediaType = "media_type"
        case type, deleted
        case createdOn = "created_on"
        case modifiedOn = "modified_on"
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried  Not working !! `Type 'VideoAlbum' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

Comment: Because it is optional !! if i provide default value then it is working Any workaround for this ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya even when you initialize it with `nil`? `var isPlaying:Bool? = nil`

Answer (score 1):

First change from type struct to class. Add a parent class that doesn't conform to Codable protocol, for example VideoAlbumStatus and add those custom properties. Now just inherit VideoAlbum from parent class.

```
class VideoAlbumStatus {
    var isPlaying:Bool? // CUSOTM PROPERTY 
    var currentTime:CMTime? // CUSOTM PROPERTY 
    var timeObserver:Any? // CUSOTM PROPERTY  
    var pausedByUser:Bool? // CUSOTM PROPERTY 
}

class VideoAlbum: VideoAlbumStatus, Codable {

    let id, image: String?
    let video, mediaType: JSONNull?
    let type, deleted, createdOn: String?
    let modifiedOn: JSONNull?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, image, video
        case mediaType = "media_type"
        case type, deleted
        case createdOn = "created_on"
        case modifiedOn = "modified_on"
    }

    //TO DO 
    // init() for VideoAlbum class

}
```