# How to add a boolean variable for each item in a list SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a menu list which has a list of items. I have a button "Order this" attached to each item. To prevent a user ordering the same menu multiple times (yes, they are not supposed to order more than one...) I want to set a boolean variable for each item. When they click "Order this", the boolean changes to true and the button changes to a text "menu ordered".

My initial attempt was to use an EnvironmentObject var:

```
class MenuState: ObservableObject {
@Published var items = [MenuItem]()
var mstate: Bool = false }
```

However, when I do this, the boolean is not assigned to each item in the list. As a result, all items in the list change when clicked.

Assigning the variable in the menu struct seems to be the solution, but I have made the items using json, which is immutable.

So, how could I attach boolean var for each item when the items are created using json?

```
struct MenuItem: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
var id: UUID
var name: String}

[
{
    "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A66",
    "name": "Dish",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "36A7CC40-18C1-48E5-BCD8-3B42D43BEAEE",
            "name": "Stack-o-Pancakes",
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add your boolean as a transient property of each `MenuItem` - the way you have it, the `mstate` refers to the entire menu:

```swift
struct MenuItem: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
var id: UUID
var name: String
var isOrdered: Bool?
}
```

There are a few ways to add a property to `MenuItem` and prevent it from being decoded: I made `isOrdered` an optional in the code here, but a better solution would be manually decoding the `MenuItem` objects, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505636/how-to-add-custom-transient-property-in-codable-struct).

Another option would be to have an array or dictionary of `Bool` values on your `MenuState`, to associate `Bool` values to a specific `MenuItem`.